# cakePHP 3 Plugin Vendor view overide not working on server - subdomain

Tags: subdomain, cakephp-3.0

I am using the `cakedc/users` plugin, I composer installed it.
`www_amar` is my subdomain directory

The view I want to overide is located in
`www_amar/vendor/cakedc/users/src/Template/Users`

And my view files are located in
`src/Template/Plugin/cakedc/users/Users`

with the same filename. I know this works because it works locally but when I upload them to my server, it's still reading from the plugin file.

How do I troubleshoot this? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the plugin in the plugin registry is not `cakedc/users` (that's the composer scope name), but `CakeDC/Users` by default (that's what's passed in the `Plugin::load()` call), which is what is used in the path when looking up possible overrides.

Unlike your local environment, your server most likely uses a case sensitive filesystem, hence it cannot find `src/Template/CakeDC/Users/...`, as it doesn't exist. Change your folder names accordingly and it should work.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Plugins > Overriding Plugin Templates from Inside Your Application](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#overriding-plugin-templates-from-inside-your-application)**